# How to determine if whether a disk was part of RAID 5 or RAID 1?

Tags: raid, nas

I have two disk I'm clearing up but I forgot whether they were part of a RAID 5 array of 4 disks or a RAID 1 array of 2 disks. Is there any traces I can look at to determine? The RAID would have been a Linux software RAID used by QNAP. The QNAP NAS model is TS-451+. The partitions look like this in the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: BTW both disks are 4GB ones. I'm not sure whether the largest partitions on both disks appear to be the size of 8GB. I'm not confident that it is indication of these being a RAID 1.

Comment: I’m not familiar with how QNAP does stuff, but did you try using `mdadm` to start the supposed array yet? I think it can also scan for arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does the command work when the drives are mounted from external USB dock? I unfortunately do not have any more bays in my NAS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log on via `ssh` as `admin` (`uid 0` - as `root` for QNAP):

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sda3

# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb3
```

(maybe disks on your NAS are different from `sda` or `sdb`, but data partition should be the third, based on your screenshot - largest partition)

For each disk you are going to get the RAID type, as similar to:

```
Raid Level : raid6
```

As you can find on [specification here](https://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/SNIA_DDF_Technical_Position_v2.0.pdf) at paragraph "4.1  Primary RAID Level" (page 13) there is a byte on each partition indicating the type of RAID to which the partition belongs.
With `mdadm --examine` you can read this attribute.

[Here mdadm source](https://github.com/pombredanne/mdadm-1/blob/master/super-ddf.c).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does the command work when the drives are mounted from external USB dock? I unfortunately do not have any more bays in my NAS...

Comment: It should work always. Of course you need to know device name `/dev/...`